# MySQL calculated column based on 2 conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate a basic 'attendance' report from a table of logs. My `logs` table appears like this:

```
TABLE logs
id  | date       | log  |
------------------------|
123 | 2018-01-01 | 1234 |
123 | 2018-01-02 |      | // Missed log
123 | 2018-01-03 | 5678 |
456 | 2018-01-01 | 5678 |
456 | 2018-01-02 | 1234 |
456 | 2018-01-03 | 1234 |
```

So an empty entry results in a missed date.

The desired `SELECT` result would be this:

```
id  | perc  |
------------|
123 | 0.666 |
456 | 1     |
```

I've tried the following but I'm not sure where to go from here:

`SELECT id, count(*) AS attended WHERE log IS NOT NULL GROUP BY id ORDER BY attended`

which yeilds:

```
id  | attended |
---------------|
123 | 2        |
456 | 3        |
```

This gets me part of the way there, but I'm not sure how I can add a `missed` column to that, and then calculate the percentage. I'll be joining the result to a 'users' table later on, so names can be associated with the logs `id`s. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CASE condition that is suggested in another answer is redundant here as [COUNT always counting NOT NULL records](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) only. As a result, you can simplify the query:

```
SELECT
      id 
    , COUNT(log) AS attended 
    , COUNT(*) - COUNT(log) AS missed
    , IF(COUNT(*) > 0, count(log) / COUNT(*), NULL) AS percentage
FROM
    logs
GROUP BY
    id 
ORDER BY
    attended
```

In addition, I've fixed percentage calculation as per OP.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks! I ended up finding that an extra `WHERE` clause was needed for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

"conditional aggregates" solve this, basically you place a `case expression` inside the `count()` function

```
SELECT
      id 
    , count(case when log IS NOT NULL then 1 end) AS attended 
    , count(case when log IS NULL then 1 end)     AS Missed
    , case when count(case when log IS NOT NULL then 1 end) > 0 then
           count(case when log IS NOT NULL then 1 end) / count(*)
           else 0
      end AS perc  
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY attended
```

If you use `count(*)` than all rows are counted, but if you count a value that can be NULL then those NULLs are not counted.